# Race condition in multiple Unicorn instances (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, concurrency

Let's say I have a controller action that takes a lot of time to perform, and does several Database operations in between, and they somehow only work well if the whole action is atomic.

If I have several instances of the application distributed in several servers, with a Nginx balance loader, in other words, if two requests hit at the same time, they would begin to process at the same time by two different servers.

What's the way to avoid problems with race condition in this case? It looks like something any distributed application would suffer from.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have a controller action that takes a lot of time to perform, and does several Database operations in between, and they somehow only work well if the whole action is atomic

If the race condition is caused by database operations, then one solution is wrapping those operations in [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) which will ensure [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties.

In Rails, you can do it by Active Record Transaction as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  database operation 1
  database operation 2
  ...
end
```

Note that Active Record Transaction is performed per database connection. If you want to wrap multiple ActiveRecord classes which are in turn stored in multiple databases, then one workaround is nested transaction

```
Class1.transaction do 
  Class2.transaction do
     database operation 1
     database operation 2
  end
end
```

But this seems not an elegant solution. More on [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Son Nguyens answer, I'd like to mention that, in addition to database transactions, it is also often helpful to lock specific records or collections when executing long-running processes.

ActiveRecord supports both [pessimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) and [optimistic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html) locking, but in my experience, pessimistic locking is often more robust in cases like this.

On a further note, depending on how long the actual operation will take, it is often a good idea to move processing into the background using [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) or similar functionality. Very long-running requests, besides having poor UX, often need special configuration on the web server. Heroku even stops processing requests after 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! Well, the process isn't long at all, but long enough for a race condition (0.001ms, 0.1ms, 2ms, 1ms, etc). (Also, who deploys serious apps on Heroku? :)...). That locking system you mention is what I was looking for. Now, I wonder how this kind of things are done in Express (Node), and other frameworks that don't seem to have this kind of things...

Comment: Row locking is a database feature that is supported by many ORMs. So is optimistic locking. Javas Hibernate and PHPs Doctrine ORM for example. On Node.js, there's Sequelize, which also seems to have full transaction and locking support (haven't used it)